# The user is not authenticated (amplify)

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'am building a backend API as NPM-package using aws-amplify and typescript.
Wrapping all functionality works good. But i have an issue loading the currentSignedIn user.

My log-in script:

```js
import {Auth} from "aws-amplify";
import "../app.config";
import {SignInOpts} from "@aws-amplify/auth/src/types";
import {CognitoUser} from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";

/**
 * @name SignIn
 * @description:
 *      sign in with username, password.
 *
 * @type function
 * @async
 * @param {string} usernameOrSignInOpts the email of the user
 * @param {string} pw the password of the user
 * @return {Promise<CognitoUser | any>}
 */
const SignIn = async (
    usernameOrSignInOpts: string | SignInOpts,
    pw?: string
): Promise<CognitoUser | any> => {
   try {
       return await Auth.signIn(usernameOrSignInOpts, pw);
   } catch (err) {
       throw err;
   }
}

export {
    SignIn
}

export default SignIn;
```

After this am trying to use sign in function (after i signed-up a new user and been confirmed). But it does catch an error: "The user is not authenticated".

I was searching a lot but no answers found for my issue.

My config file:

```js
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsExports from './aws-exports';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

Amplify.configure(awsExports);
dotenv.config();
```

Script where sign in works:

```js
import {SignUp, ConfirmSignUp, ResendSignUp} from "./Authentication/SignUp";
import SignIn from "./Authentication/SignIn";
import Validator from "./Services/Validator";
import {RegexPatterns, RegexTypes} from "./Enums/Regex";
import SignOut from "./Authentication/SignOut";
import DeleteUser from "./Authentication/DeleteUser";
import UserManagement, {ChangePassword} from "./Authentication/UserManagement";
import "./app.config";
import {Auth} from "aws-amplify";
import NotAuthorizedException from "./Exceptions/NotAuthorizedException";

export default {
    SignIn,
    SignUp,
    SignOut,
    ConfirmSignUp,
    ResendSignUp,
    Validator,
    UserManagement,
    RegexPatterns,
    DeleteUser,
}

SignIn('xxxxxx', 'xxxx').then(() =>
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    .then(authenticatedUser => {
        console.log(authenticatedUser);
    }).catch(err => {
        throw new NotAuthorizedException(err);
}));
```

But if i seperate Sign-in function and cuurentAuthenticatedUser i will get an error.
My question is does sign-in save a session for the user somewhere? I want to be able to call cuurentAuthenticatedUser in another file in my application and get the current user.

In short, Why signIn function is not able to save a session with my logged-in user? I can only login at the same runtime and after that the user is not authenticated.

help pls!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Op, you may need to add a conditional statement, like so:

```
if (!authenticatedUser) return <Authenticator /> (or your custom sign in component);
```

Comment: Thanks that what i've done exactly :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **useAuthenticator** hook to check the logged-in user in react functional component.

```js
import { useAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

const Home = () => {
  const { user, signOut } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.user]);

  return <button onClick={signOut}>Welcome, {user.username}!</button>;
};
```

You can use useAuthenticator hook to access **route** string that represents the current **authState**.

```js
import { useAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

const App = () => {
  const { route } = useAuthenticator(context => [context.route]);

  // Use the value of route to decide which page to render
  return route === 'authenticated' ? <Home /> : <Authenticator />;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but am trying to build custom flow auth and i do not need the ui component to be used.